# Throwing exceptions from Spring REST webservice as JSON/XML

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, exception

I have a REST web service controller that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = URIConstants.URL_DOCUMENT_SEARCH, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
protected DocumentSearchResponse getDocuments(@Valid @ModelAttribute   DocumentSearchRequest objDMSRequest,BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest objServletRequest) throws AppException
{
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) 
    {
       //I want to throw my custom exception here 
 ///Or can anyone suggest a more clean and efficient way

    }
-----More code and logic
}
```

I have a custom exception and handlers that will throw invalid HTTP invalid request exception. The custom exception has errorcode and error description fields. 
My requirement is is there a way to parse the error from the bindingresults to a custome exception and trow that in the controler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(errorDescription,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Or, you can do it hardcore if you really want to use Exception(not recommended):

```
try {
   throw new CustomException();
} catch(CustomException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getErrorDescription(),e.getStatusCode());
}
```

By the way: returning a Exception it's not good, that's why I don't show it.

Comment: thats a wonderful suggestion . Can you please tell me what will you suggest when my controller looks something like this:

Comment: Can u please suggest what if my controller looks like :       @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public <custom Response Bean POJO> getResults(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {

Comment: With public ResponseEntity , you can return your POJO normally. return new ResponseEntity<>(yourPOJO, HttpStatus.OK); Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134331/how-to-respond-with-http-status-code-in-a-spring-mvc-restcontroller-responsebo

Answer (score 0):

Its is as simple as that 
1. Create a class which extends Exception.

```
 class MyCustomException extends Exception{
     MyCustomException(){
     }
     MyCustomException(Object e){
         super(e)
     }
 }
```

2. Make your code throw same type of exception

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity create(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        try{
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                throw new MyCustomException();
            }
        } catch(MyCustomException e){
            //do what ever you want to do with it
        }
        ...
}
```

3. Man you already done... :)

Answer (score 0):

@Albert-Pinto first of all the way you are trying to do this is completely wrong. If you want to consume a object it should come as @RequestBody and not as just a simple object. What you have done in your example is a MVC way which we do with the web applications, not the way we do for web service. so the above code will become as

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/user")
 public class UserController {
   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody User user) {
   try {
       throw new CustomException();
    } catch(CustomException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getErrorDescription(),e.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```