# how to throws error when use request with method Options and Head in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to response like this

`{
    "status": 405,
    "message": "method not allowed"
}`

Any recommend please advice thank you!

Comment: Look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134331/how-to-respond-with-http-status-code-in-a-spring-mvc-restcontroller-responsebo/26134433

Answer (score 0):

Create a pojo using both fields and getter/setter.

```
public class ResponseDetails{
  private String status;
  private String message;

 //getters and setters
}
```

and then convert this pojo to json and send the response like below :

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
return new ResponseEntity<String>(new JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class").serialize(responseDetails),headers,  HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
```

NOTE : Please set the values using setters before sending response.